# i am trying to connect reactjs axios with django rest framework to make the post request. but i am getting POST 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

here is axios code:

```
axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/form/',
      data: this.state,
      headers: {    
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
```

here is views.py

```
class Formview(APIView):
    def post(self,request):
        Fprov=request.POST.get('selectedPro')
        Fdist=request.POST.get('selectedDistrict')
        FpalikaT=request.POST.get('selectedPalikaType')
        FpalikaN=request.POST.get('enteredPalikaName')
        FWardN=request.POST.get('enteredWardNo')
        FWardOf=request.POST.get('enteredWardOfficeAddress')
        FWardC=request.POST.get('enteredWardContactNo')
        new=Form(Province=Fprov,
             District=Fdist,
             PalikaType=FpalikaT,
             PalikaName=FpalikaN,
             Ward_No=FWardN,
             Ward_Office_Address=FWardOf,
             Ward_Contact_No=FWardC)
        new.save()
```

here is serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Form

class FormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Form
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a view to handle the request data using your `FormSerializer`. I recommend creating a class based view because it makes creating APIs pretty easy. The Django Rest Framework has great documentation on how to create these views here : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/ . Create the view and pass your data into the serializer as `request.data` and not `request.POST`.